# How to display contours (openCV) on an image in a HMI (pyQt) - Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, pyqt, contour

I am developping a tool for a project of my engineering school. This is my first time making a HMI and using `openCV` and `qtpy`.

My goal is to apply a first treatment on the image (blur and stuff) to make it easier to detect the contours of a plum. Then I want to display the contours of the plum found using the `openCV` `findContour` method. For the time being i managed to display the contours through the `openCV` method `drawContours` however it opens a new window through `matplot` instead of displaying the contours on top of the image that is already displayed in my MHI.

How can I do to not display the contours in a new matplot window but on top of my already displayed image in my HMI ?

Here is what my HMI looks like.

[image]

Here is my code concerning the contours display which uses `drawContours` method.

```
def allContours(img_originale, masque, toggleMode) :
    if toggleMode :
        #trouve les contours sur l'image
        image_copy = img_originale.copy()
        contours, hier = cv2.findContours(image=masque, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cv2.drawContours(image=image_copy, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
        cv2.imshow('Contours', image_copy)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
    else :
        pass
```

And here is the code part that displays my image in the HMI :

```
 # Redimensionnement et affichage Image
        image = cv2.resize(image, (int(self.ratio*self.image_w),int(self.ratio*self.image_h)))
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height, width, channels = image.shape
        step =  channels*width
        qImg = QImage(image.data, width, height, step, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qImg))
```

I would like to obtain the following result but have it in the HMI instead of a new window. Can anyone tell me how to do ? Thank you !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if we could see more of your code but basically you can just return the image with the drawn contours:

```
def allContours(img_originale, masque, toggleMode) :
    if toggleMode :
        #trouve les contours sur l'image
        image_copy = img_originale.copy()
        contours, hier = cv2.findContours(image=masque, mode=cv2.RETR_TREE, method=cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
        cv2.drawContours(image=image_copy, contours=contours, contourIdx=-1, color=(0, 255, 0), thickness=2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
        return image_copy
    else :
        return None
```

Also tweak your "blur and stuff" preprocessing a bit. It should be possible to get even better results. Maybe try Canny edge detection.